Why Async calls running after code completion C# .NET
Async Http calls not working properly in side Threadpool Queue
I have also tried by increasing loop value 1000 .
Expectations: All Async calls should run parallel with the loop, so it should get results and print "End Thread"  message in between running code .
I have added two demonstration Try 1 & Try 2. But Result getting from Try 2 is fulfill my expectations but i want to use Thread Pool.
try 1-
 
 int i = 1;
 while (i<=1000)
 {
     //ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AsyncHttpCall); ||  Task.Run(() => AsyncHttpCall(null)); || Task.Factory.StartNew(() => AsyncHttpCall(null)); --Tried All Ways
     ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AsyncHttpCall);
     i++;
 }

public async void AsyncHttpCall(object state)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    Console.WriteLine("Thread Start: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    HttpResponseMessage response =await client.GetAsync("https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread End: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}

Try 1 Result (Different From Expectation)
Thread Start: 12
Thread Start: 13
Thread Start: 15
Thread Start: 10
Thread Start: 14
Thread Start: 5
Thread Start: 7
Thread Start: 9
Thread Start: 17
Thread Start: 18
Thread End: 12
Thread End: 9
Thread End: 18
Thread End: 7
Thread End: 14
Thread End: 10
Thread End: 13
Thread End: 17
Thread End: 15
Thread End: 5

try 2-
 
 int i = 1;
while (i<=1000)
{
    new Thread(AsyncHttpCall).Start();
    i++;
}

public async void AsyncHttpCall(object state)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    Console.WriteLine("Thread Start: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    HttpResponseMessage response =await client.GetAsync("https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread End: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}

Try 2 Result (Correct as Expectation)
Thread Start: 12
Thread Start: 13
Thread Start: 15
Thread Start: 10
Thread Start: 14
Thread End: 12
Thread Start: 5
Thread Start: 7
Thread Start: 9
Thread Start: 17
Thread End: 9
Thread Start: 18
Thread End: 18
Thread End: 7
Thread End: 14
Thread End: 10
Thread End: 13
Thread End: 17
Thread End: 15
Thread End: 5


"Async Call should run in-between threads" Can you elaborate on what you expect? What exactly should happen from your perspective?

I'm not sure what your expectation is.  "Async call should run in between threads?"  It appears that those calls are succeeding, based on the console output.

GetAsync starts the request and returns a Task you could await. Accessing the Result property of that task blocks execution until the async operation is finished. Your output looks exaclty like what I would expect from your code.

You probably want to avoid QueueUserWorkItem. Use Task.Run and Task.WhenAll, or possibly Task.WaitAll, to ensure all calls complete before the application terminates.

That is not how to use HttpClient

@RobertHarvey Question Modified. Please help me to reopen this. And I want that async call should run it between also , for now these running after loop completetion.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain Question Modified. Please help me to reopen this. And I want that async call should run it between also , for now these running after loop completetion.

@RenéVogt Question Modified. Please help me to reopen this. Here the loop value is dynamic and async calls should run in between also of the loop.

Your expectation describes an implementation detail, but what exactly are you trying to achieve?  Better performance?  How much better performance?

Apparently you are observing the effects of a (very briefly) saturated ThreadPool. When the ThreadPool receives a huge amount of work, its behavior is not to create an equally huge number of threads to accommodate the demand. Instead it creates immediately a few number of threads, equal by default¹ to the number of cores of the machine (Environment.ProcessorCount), and then waits until one of these threads completes a unit of work before assigning to it the next scheduled unit of work. At this point we say that the ThreadPool is saturated. The requests for work are served in (roughly) FIFO order. If none of the threads has completed its work after one second², only then the ThreadPool will inject one more thread to the pool, increasing the number of the available worker threads (ThreadPool.ThreadCount).
What happens in your case is that you immediately schedule to the ThreadPool the beginning of all the asynchronous operations, but these operations require the ThreadPool to make progress. The HttpClient.GetAsync asynchronous method returns a Task that completes on the ThreadPool. So there is additional work requested from the ThreadPool after the beginning of the asynchronous operations. This additional work has lower priority than the initial work, because of the FIFO behavior of the ThreadPool. So it's only reasonable that you see in the console all the "Thread Start" messages before seeing the first "Thread End" message.
¹ Configurable with the ThreadPool.SetMinThreads API.
² The injection rate of the ThreadPool is not documented. As of .NET 8 it is experimentally found to be one new thread per second, but this could change in future .NET versions.

If you look at ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem, you'll note that it only has an Action<> overload, not a Func<Task> overload, which means that it cannot track continuations for you:
public static bool QueueUserWorkItem<TState> (Action<TState> callBack, TState state, bool preferLocal);

A much better option would be Task.Run, which does have a Func<Task> overload, but that's just plain silly: your function is already an async task, you just wrote it wrong. It should return a Task object:
public async Task AsyncHttpCall(object state)

Once done, you can then start your calls and await their completion:
await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(0, 1000), _ => AsyncHttpCall(null))
    .ConfigureAwait(false);

Written as above, all tasks will run in parallel.
Unrelated, but you should also stop forcing continuations back on previous contexts (.ConfigureAwait(false)) and stop looking at native thread IDs. Proper async code here will have your tasks jumping between physical threads as needed.
